# How does df.interpolate(inplace=True) function?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filter, inplace-editing

I am having trouble understanding how this functions. With inplace=True, the function doesn't output anything and the original df remains unchanged. How does this work?

So sorry I wrote 'filter' in my first post. That was very stupid mistake.

As @Alex requested, the example is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,3), columns=map(chr, range(65,68)))
df['B'] = np.nan
print df
print df.interpolate(axis=1)
print df
print df.interpolate(axis=1, inplace=True)
print df
```

The output is as follows:

```
     A       B         C
0 -0.956273 NaN  0.919723
1  1.127298 NaN -0.585326
2 -0.045163 NaN -0.946355
3 -1.375863 NaN -1.279663

      A         B         C
0 -0.956273 -0.018275  0.919723
1  1.127298  0.270986 -0.585326
2 -0.045163 -0.495759 -0.946355
3 -1.375863 -1.327763 -1.279663

      A   B         C
0 -0.956273 NaN  0.919723
1  1.127298 NaN -0.585326
2 -0.045163 NaN -0.946355
3 -1.375863 NaN -1.279663

None

      A   B         C
0 -0.956273 NaN  0.919723
1  1.127298 NaN -0.585326
2 -0.045163 NaN -0.946355
3 -1.375863 NaN -1.279663
```

As you can see, the first interpolation created a copy of the original dataframe. What I wanted is to interpolate and update the original dataframe, so I tried `inplace` since the documentation states the follow:

**inplace : bool, default False
Update the NDFrame in place if possible.**

The second interpolation did not return any value, and it did not update the original dataframe. So I'm confused.

And as @joris requested, my pandas version is `'0.15.1'`. Though this request is due to my mistake...

Comment: What version of pandas do you have? I am getting "filter() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inplace'"

Comment: @Alex An example has been updated

Comment: @joris I made a mistake, it's interpolate, not filter. But still, is it possible to filter out just a view of the subset of the original dataframe?

Comment: This was probably a bug. I cannot reproduce with the current version of pandas, the inplace parameter works fine.